# how to trigger a custom event in jQuery, pass the original event and data

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger a custom event from within a handler of a native event, under these conditions:

- I want the handler to be in the form: `function(event, arg) {}`, where
- `event` is the original, native event (so I can call `event.preventDefault()`)
- `arg` is some data passed by the `trigger`er (in the handler of the original event)
- both events (native & custom) are fired on the same element (so the custom event's name must differ from the original one)

I was able to get this far, and it works:

```js
// the native event handler 
function(event) {
    var e = jQuery.Event("some_custom_event");
    e.foo = 'bar';
    $(this).trigger(e);
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented())
        event.preventDefault();
}

// an example handler for the custom event:
function (event) {
    alert(event.foo);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I guess I could also pass both the original event and `foo` as arguments to the custom event handler, but I wanted a standard-looking handler (no `function(event1,event2`).

Can what I want be done (easily) in jQuery?

Answer (score 5):

The `trigger` function has 2 flavors and I think you should look at the first one which is of syntax `.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] )`.

If I understood correctly then what you need to do is you pass `foo` as additional param like below,

```
$(this).trigger(e, [foo]);
```

An example from jQuery documentation is below,

```
$("p").click( function (event, a, b) {
// when a normal click fires, a and b are undefined
// for a trigger like below a refers to "foo" and b refers to "bar"

} ).trigger("click", ["foo", "bar"]);
```

From documentation.. [read more..](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> **.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] )**
>
> eventTypeA string containing a JavaScript event type, such as click or
>   submit.
>
> extraParametersAdditional parameters to pass along to the event
>   handler.

Comment: Your solution doen't allow me to `preventDefault` on the original event in the custom event handler.

Comment: @ori Can you elaborate what is supposed to happen on `preventDefault`? Was it working in first place? I am sure adding addition param is not going to impact anything which was working before.

Comment: First, I made a mistake in the code above, have a look. I'm building a jQuery plugin which I want to be able to interact with. Maybe some kind of callback is a better fit. Basically I wanted a custom event handler that can refer to the original event (can call `preventDefault` on it), but if I do `.trigger('custom', [event, foo])` then the handler becomes `function(c_event, n_event, foo) {}` which looked ugly.

Comment: @ori You can try passing the arg inside another array like `$(this).trigger(custom, [[event, foo]]);` and the custom event will be like `$('a').bind('some_custom_event', function (e, args)` and then you can access original event in `args[0]` and `foo` in args[1]. [See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/FUnDB/)

Comment: It's new code I wrote. There was no code before. The code I presented in my question works, but I wanted to see if some jQuery genius can improve it. I'm also using the first `.trigger` flavor elsewhere, but using it here means that (in order to meet my requirements) the handler would need to get 2 events as arguments, which I don't like (and therefore never implemented). Maybe I'm asking for too much... the first handler argument is always the fired event, so maybe my original solution can't be improved...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a JQuery Event (`$.Event`), which will allow for `event.preventDefault()` and will be honored or picked up after the event was triggered.

So, first create the event in your plugin/function, and trigger it:

```
var event = $.Event('myCustomEvent');
$element.triggerHandler(event, [extraData1, extraData2]);
```

Then in your handler, you can get access to your extraData and preventDefault;

```
$('#someElement').on('myCustomEvent', function (event, extraData1, extraData2) {
   event.preventDefault();
};
```

Now you can check after the original trigger to see of default was prevented;

```
var event = $.Event('myCustomEvent');
$element.triggerHandler(event, [extraData1, extraData2]);

if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    /* Do something as user prevented default */
} else {
    /* Proceed as normal */
};
```